# CRM2011 Plugin Service for Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to provide a bunch of CRM Entities from CRM2011 to a Silverlight App trough a Plugin?

Adding the WSDL Url to Silverlight failed and the generated Context with CRMSVCUTIL can't be added to a Silverlight Project.

What is the best approach to get the Entities?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through a plugin.

You will probably want to use the SOAP or REST endpoint, for both, samples are available on the MSDN.

Start here: [Use Web Service Data in Web Resources (REST and SOAP Endpoint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490659.aspx)

(Web Resource in this context includes Silverlight).

Pick the endpoint you wish to use, then drill down to the articles beneath, should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had already seen this possibilities but I thought it works like Plugin Development or something like that.
I'm probably going to use SOAP endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the CSDL file for use in Silvelight.  That should be available in Developer Resources in Settings.  Once you have that, google will be your friend.  (I would put more but unable to browse at the moment).